# How to use inline_keyboard instead of keyboard in Telegram bot (Python)?

Tags: python, keyboard, telegram, telegram-bot

I have this part of code (Python) that I'm using in my Telegram bot:

```
def reply(msg=None, img=None):
        if msg:
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'sendMessage', urllib.urlencode({
                'chat_id': str(chat_id),
                'text': msg.encode('utf-8'),
                'disable_web_page_preview': 'true',
                # 'reply_to_message_id': str(message_id),
                'reply_markup': json.dumps({'keyboard': [bline1, bline2], 'resize_keyboard': True}),
            })).read()
```

For this part everything works fine. The question is: how to use inline_keyboard intead of regular keyboard?

I understand that it is a noob question, but it would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the [Inline Keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) is just a different json object, I'd say you only have to build it with `json.dumps` instead of your current build. Following your example, something like this should make the trick:

```
def reply(msg=None, img=None):
        if msg:
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'sendMessage', urllib.urlencode({
                'chat_id': str(chat_id),
                'text': msg.encode('utf-8'),
                'disable_web_page_preview': 'true',
                # 'reply_to_message_id': str(message_id),
                'reply_markup': json.dumps({'inline_keyboard': [[{'text': bline1, 'callback_data': bline1}, {'text': bline2, 'callback_data': bline2}]]}),
            })).read()
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it's not working - the bot just stop responding, I've tried this. Stil couldn't find out what is the problem.

Comment: `json_keyboard = json.dumps({keym: [[{'text': 'b2', 'callback_data': '6'}]]})` - this approach worked, thanks!